# Ansible: How to join a variable with the range of strings

Tags: python, ansible

```
- hosts:all

  tasks:

  - name: set fact joing the variable and the range of strings
    set_fact:
        exclude_addrs: "{{ split_addr | join('.')[1-5] }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

In my case split_addr is 10.0.0 and output that I'm expecting is 
10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.4, 10.0.0.5

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you are trying and expecting? Are you just looking for `['10.0.0.%d'%i for i in range(1,6)]`

Comment: I was trying to add the A records in the DNS. But Exclude first 5 addresses. The above script is my pre task there is an other TASK under that to add the A records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly in your vars without having to run a task.

Here is the fastest example I could think of:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    split_addr: "10.0.0"
    range_length: 5
    exclude_addrs: >-
      {{
        range(1, range_length+1) |
        map('regex_replace', '([0-9]*)', split_addr + '.\1') |
        list
      }}

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: exclude_addrs
```

Possible further readings:

- [range function](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#range)
- [map filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#map)
- [regular expression filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters)